# Step per range HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to set the step between the display lines in Highcharts. I mean it -

200

150

100

50

0
In this y-case step = 50. How can i set this in HighCharts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This found with the [`yAxis.tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval). For example:

```
yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 50
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Please tell me, what I can reduce the height of the graph without losing a this step? When I reduce height from 700px to 400px - step increase, and still 100...

Comment: @Walllter, highcharts will try and auto-scale the chart as well. You may need to set the yAxis.min/max values as well.